# How to recenter a dialog vertically?

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm working on a mobile version of a website and I have a jQuery UI dialog sized at 100% of the screen width and height with text inputs and a textarea in it. When the user presses on an input, it is selected and the phone pushes the dialog up in order to show the keyboard. The problem is that when the user presses out of the input (dis-selecting it), the phone's keyboard disappears and the dialog is still "pushed up." So, what I need to do is recenter the dialog vertically after the keyboard slides back down.

I can add an event handler to the inputs that runs when they are dis-selected, but I'm unsure of how to recenter the dialog vertically.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have done some more searching before asking, because I just stumbled across the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3060895/1101095

I'll leave the question here in case it helps someone with the same problem. Here's the code from the above solution inside a `.blur()` handler:

```
$("input, textarea").blur(function() {
    $(".ui-dialog-content").dialog("option", "position", "center"); // resize the (technically all) dialog
});
```

That fixes the issue!