# Automatically readjust the position of jquery ui-dialog as window size changes

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a `dialog` declaration that goes like this,

```
                    $('#login_modal').dialog({
                        autoOpen: false,
                        modal: true,
                        resizable: false,
                        fluid: true,
                        width: "35%",   // this is experimental; depends on the window size
                        height: "450",
                        show: {
                            effect: "blind",
                            duration: 500
                        },
                        hide: {
                            effect: "blind",
                            duration: 200
                        },
                        create: function(event, ui){

                            // sets transparent bg for ui-dialog
                            $('.ui-dialog').attr('style','background: red !important; border: 0px !important; max-width: 800px !important; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%;');

                            // sets css for overlay wrapper
                            $(".ui-widget-overlay").attr('style','background-color: #FFFFFF !important; opacity:0.55; z-index:1; width: 100%; height: 100%; display: none;');

                            // removes modal header
                            $(this).siblings('.ui-dialog-titlebar').remove();

                            // background for .ui-widget-content
                            $('.ui-widget-content').css({'background':'transparent !important','border':'0px !important', 'width':'100% !important'});

                        },
                        open: function(){

                            // sets transparent bg for ui-dialog
                            $('.ui-dialog').css({"background":"transparent !important", "maxHeight": "400px !important"}); 

                            // applies CSS for the overlay
                            $(".ui-widget-overlay").attr('style','background-color: #FFFFFF !important; opacity:0.55; z-index:15; width: 100%; height: 100%;');

                            // bind click event so when user clicks on overlay it closes
                            $(".ui-widget-overlay").bind('click', function() {
                                $("#login_modal").dialog('close');
                            });

                            $('div.login-content').css({"height": "auto"});
                        },
                        close: function(){
                            //
                        }
                    });
```

I have also set the `css` for the dialog the way I want it. Currently it is now positioned on the center. What I want to happen is that when I try to adjust the window size, the position of the dialog will also adjust, from right-left or left-right vice versa. How would I do this via css or jquery? That is what I have tried so far. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day of research, I finally found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060146/how-to-auto-center-jquery-ui-dialog-when-resizing-browser).

It turns out there is something lacking on my code which forces the dialog to be positioned at center every time the window resizes, this code is lacking,

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog("option", "position", "center");
});
```

Hope this helps anyone. :)