# How to display popup in center of a page for all browser's and devices using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I tried to display popup in center for my site from all browser & devices. Is it possible to handle this thing using javascript or jquery.
Thanks.

Comment: show us your code please

Comment: btw everythng is possible with js jquery ;)

Comment: ya thats y m asking this. is there any way to globaly handle this problem

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/ see this link

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see how and what to ask here. HINT: Show effort and code

Comment: similarly no need to comment everytime & everyplaces if not interested. thanks.

Comment: It has nothing to do with not being interested - it has to do with letting you know why your question may be voted down and closed and prepare you for it. This question is not only off-topic because it has no code or effort, it is also a HUGE FAQ that you could have found answer to with a search faster than writing the question - I am considering closing it as duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060146/how-to-auto-center-jquery-ui-dialog-when-resizing-browser

Comment: actually first of all i tried to find this and no one is perfect in the begining.

Comment: if you are going for an interview and interviewer asked you the same question than is the same your answer which u told me.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div style="position:fixed;left:0px;right:0px;top:0px;bottom:0px;width:150px;height:90px;margin:auto;background:white;    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #888888;
"></div>
```